# Change order of characters in a string in powershell

Tags: powershell-4.0

I have a thumbprint of a certificate stored in a variable and I need to change the order of its characters to write it to a registry value. If the thumbprint is like 1234567890, I need to change order of characters to 9078563412 - basically split the string to couples and write the couples in the reversed order. I don't know, how long the string will be, so I can't work with static positions of characters.

First problem is that when I tried `$Thumbprint.ToString().length` the result was 0, although it should've been 38. I tried to convert the Thumbprint variable to a new variable of the string type. When I used `$ThumbString = $Thumbprint.ToString()`, the $ThumbString variable is empty. I guess I will need to know the length for the conversion, even though I'm not sure of that. I also didn't find a way to split a string without using a delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution in one script on the net. This command does that:

```
$certSerialReversed = ""
-1..-38 |% {$certSerialReversed += $certSerial[2*$_] + $certSerial[2*$_ + 1]}
```

I found that it doesn't really matter how high the last number is (whether it is -1..-10 or -1..-50), so I just set the longest length a thumbprint can have.